# back button bring back previous data - Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to make routing in such a way that if i went from one route(say 'r1') to other route(say 'r2') i.e. r1-> r2 and then when i again come back to r1 by using `this._location.back()` where _location is imported as `import { Location } from '@angular/common';`

```
constructor(private _location: Location) {}
```

Is there any way by which i can make sure that when i came back to 'r1' then all the previous data on that page are can be used again without calling services.

consider example:
r1 component has member `myList = [1,2,3,4]`(data from http service). then i navigate to r2 and then using back button as above. Now i come back to r1 component. Is there any way i can get r1 component to same state when i leave it.

> NOTE: Without using dataservices(saving in any service/localstorage etc.)
>   Its should be like ionic push and pop view.

Comment: Use a service to do this.. Store your data that you are sharing between the components in that service.

Comment: "NOTE: Without using dataservices(saving in any service/localstorage etc.)"

Comment: Take a look at **[distinctUntilChanged](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/distinctuntilchanged.md)**, but if you want to make no HTTP calls, you wil have to use a sharing service.